# MySQL query not running properly

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason my SQL command is just obviously not running properly. When this is called:

```
$title = $_POST['event_title'];
$title = mb_convert_encoding($title, "HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8');

$event_id = $db->query("SELECT event_id FROM events WHERE event_title = '{$title}'")->fetch_object()->event_id;
```

I get 0 results but I know I should get one. I have echo'd out the query which was `SELECT event_id FROM events WHERE event_title = 'Improving young people’s health'` which is exactly what I want. If I open PHPMyAdmin and copy paste that query I get one row returned as expected, but for some reason it is not being returned when I'm calling `query()` on `$db`

Comment: check for errors via PHP and MySQL.

Comment: My guess is the ' in people's is causing the SQL to end early and throwing an error you're not trapping for.  better off to use prepared statements to avoid this type of error and the SQL injection you're potentially allowing.

Comment: SQL errno is 0 and there are no PHP errors or warnings. I have literally no idea what is going on

Comment: What's your table's encoding, the client encoding and the default DB encoding?

Comment: @apokryfos Table: latin1_swedish_ci; Client: UTF-8; DB default: uft8-unicode_ci

Comment: Split it into seperate calls and see what happens then, testing the result of each call for errors. Something in that object list is failing and feturning you false i.e. 0

Comment: I assume this is PDO right?

Comment: Do we assume you have set PDO to throw Exceptions? Do we assume you have looked at the PHP Error log? What else should we assume, of course being aware that assumption is the mother of all screw-ups

Comment: Can you do a `print_r(htmlentities($title))` I suspect that weird looking quote is HTML encoded but is stored as a single character in the DB?

Comment: `print_r(htmlentities($title))` returns Improving children and young people&rsquo;s health. How do I stop that?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: If I  use `$data = mysql_query("SELECT event_id FROM events WHERE event_title = '{$_POST['event_title']}'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
        $event_id = $row['event_id'];
    }` it works. Why does procedural, deprecated methods work but not oo non deprecated work?